# Help with 3d animation study

Tags: animation

i have been interested in 3d animationsince im a little kid, in the last year i decided to actually go for it. The problem is that i live in a 3rd world country, so im trying to go and study in japan. Im having trouble finding an specific degree in 3d animation or special fx. I woulld really appreciate if you could help me with this by finding what colleges actually teach this. Thanks for the help.
Rodrigo Monteros

Comment: While I'm sure the community here would like to be helpful, Blender SE is quite strict about being  a site to answer questions on Blender in particular. You may have better luck on threads like [this one](http://forums.cgsociety.org/forumdisplay.php?f=283)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about animation education, not Blender.